# How Construction function creates key value pair from argument passed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the constructor function below

```
function Person(first, last, age){
 this.name = {
  first,
  last
 };
 this.age = age;
};
```

Now we create an `object` with the above constructor function

```
var person1 = new Person('Bob', 'Smith',32);
```

Now if we do `console.log(person1.name)` we get following output in the `console`

```
{ first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith' }
```

I would like to know how this happen, that it's able to create key as `first` and value as `Bob` and similarly with `last`.Also, same output is logged if we change the `this.name` property in the `constructor` as follows

```
this.name = {
  first:first,
  last:last
 };
```

Comment: This is EcmaScript 6 shorthand. `{x, y}` is short for `{x:x, y:y}`

Comment: That's interesting, TIL.

Comment: @Barmar I actually found it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS#Creating_our_finished_constructor). I don't think it's ES6, even though can't confirm

Comment: Yes it's ES6 (AKA EcmaScript 2015). See the duplicate question.